# Python: calling 'curses' twice stuffs up my terminal

Tags: python, terminal, curses

I'm using `curses` for a puzzle in a terminal game (Mac OSX, Python 2.6.5). The puzzle involves spinning some dials to open a lock. My code, somewhat simplified (excuse the ugliness):

```
import curses

dial = ["| -1  |","|-1/3 |","|  0  |","| 1/2 |","| 2/3 |","|  1  |"]

clear = "       "
pointer = "   ^   "
subdials = [clear,clear]

d = {'d0':{},'d1':{}}
d['d0'] = {'val':2,'disp':dial[2]}
d['d1'] = {'val':2,'disp':dial[2]}

def spin(scr):
    try:
        curses.curs_set(0)
    except:
        pass

    solved = 0
    p = 0
    subdials[p] = pointer
    dials = [d['d0']['disp'],d['d1']['disp']]

    maxy,maxx = scr.getmaxyx()

    newscr = scr.subwin(10,51,maxy-15,0)
    newscr.box(ord('|'),ord('-'))
    newscr.addstr(4,8,''.join(dials))
    newscr.addstr(6,8,''.join(subdials))
    newscr.refresh()

    while solved == 0:
        r = scr.getch()
        subdials[p] = clear
        currd = 'd'+str(p)

        if r == ord('q') or r == ord('Q'):
            break
        elif r == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            if p > 0 and p < 2:
                p -= 1
            else: pass
        elif r == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            if p >= 0 and p < 1:
                p += 1
            else: pass
        elif r == curses.KEY_UP:
            if d[currd]['val'] >= 0 and d[currd]['val'] < 5:
                d[currd]['val'] += 1
                d[currd]['disp'] = dial[d[currd]['val']]
            else: pass
        elif r == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            if d[currd]['val'] > 0 and d[currd]['val'] <= 5:
                d[currd]['val'] -= 1
                d[currd]['disp'] = dial[d[currd]['val']]
            else: pass
        else: pass

        subdials[p] = pointer
        dials = [d['d0']['disp'],d['d1']['disp']]

        newscr.addstr(4,8,''.join(dials))
        newscr.addstr(6,8,''.join(subdials))
        newscr.refresh()

        if d['d0']['val'] == 5 and d['d1']['val'] == 3:
            solved = 1

    if solved == 0:
        scr.addstr(maxy-1,0,"You can't figure out the lock.")
    else:
        scr.addstr(maxy-1,0,"The lock is open!")
    scr.getch()
    scr.clear()
    return solved

def box():
    solved = curses.wrapper(spin)
    return solved
```

There are two ways to exit the 'box' function: by pressing 'q' to quit, or by solving the puzzle. The first time you exit from curses (in either way), no problem. But if I call 'box' again, a problem quickly arises.

First, within the curses window, any key input which my function has been instructed to `pass` is echoed to the screen. Second, and worse, when you exit the puzzle a second time – either by quitting or winning – `noecho` and `cbreak` aren't turned off, so my terminal is stuffed and has to be reset.

(NB: If I keep calling 'box', key input is no longer echoed in the curses window itself, but my terminal doesn't go back to normal.)

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's causing this behaviour. Help!

Comment: Hello Nrvous. I tried running your game in my console and it exited outright, e.g. *python curses.py* terminated immediately. How are you running it? Second, you could try running your code with the cProfile module to see if there are any excessive function calls - *python -m cProfile curses.py*. This could indicate an infinite loop.

Comment: @Aaron Newton - Thanks for the response. I run the python interpreter, import everything from the script, then call the `box` function. In the long run, that's what I intend to do – call the function from within my main game script, rather than running this script independently. I tried adding a line to this script calling `box()`, and ran it using cProfile – it didn't seem to turn up anything untoward.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I've attempted the following: `>>> import curses_prog as game
>>> run = game.box
>>> run
<function box at 0x00000000022ABC18>
>>> run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "curses_prog.py", line 78, in box
    solved = curses.wrapper(spin)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrapper'` (sorry about the formatting here). This may just be being ignorant or my implementation of Python, but I couldn't get it to run.

Comment: I think the second line should be `run = game.box()`, with parentheses? Does that fix it?

Comment: Ah! - `>>> import curses.wrapper as cw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wrapper` http://bugs.python.org/issue6771 - *Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32*

Comment: Oh – I don't think `curses` runs on Windows. I should have specificed that I'm using OS X. Seems there are Windows alternatives - `PDcurses` or `UniCurses` might do the job?

Comment: For whatever it is worth, this code works fine for me on FreeBSD (Python 2.7).  Sure smells like a bug in the OSX port.

Comment: @torek Thanks, that's all I needed to hear. I updated Python to 2.7.3, and the problem has vanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated Python to 2.7.3, and the problem has vanished. Huzzah!